# Extracting Byte Arrays from a File

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to read a file and extract 2 blocks of data, let's call them block1 and block2, from the file where the file would contain many blocks of data. Both blocks need to be 
returned in a byte array. Block1 would begin at place in the file where the line begins 
"block1:" followed by the number of bytes to read. Block2, not necessarily appearing after 
block1, would begin at place in the file where the line begins "block2:" followed by the 
number of bytes to read. I am limited to .Net 3.5 at the highest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) and extract your blocks from the returned `byte[]` using one of the [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) overloads if you know the indexes they are in.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the indexes they are in.

Comment: @Ray Bass - What _do_ you know about the blocks? You didn't really provide any information in your question. Please edit it and add relevant information, so people can give a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without any sort of header information in your file, you'll have to scan the entire file, searching for your `block1:` or `block2:` markers.

**Update:**

Here's a sample of how you'd do this (not necessarily the best implementation):

```
byte[] GetBlockOfData(string fileName, string blockName)
{
    var allBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    // Assuming block names are ASCII-encoded
    var blockMarker = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blockName + ":"); 

    // Scan for the first byte of the marker
    for (var i = 0; i < allBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (allBytes[i] == blockMarker[i])
        {
            // See if this is the entire marker
            var isMatch == true;
            for (var j = 0; j < blockMarker.Length; j++)
            {
                if (allBytes[i + j] != blockMarker[j])
                {
                    isMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isMatch)
            {
                // Assuming it's a byte...
                var blockLength = allBytes[i + blockMarker.Length];
                var result = new byte[blockLength];
                Array.Copy(
                    allBytes, i + blockMarker.Length + 1, result, 0,
                    blockLength);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree. Do you have any sample code showing how this might be done?

Comment: See my update.  The code makes some assumptions, so check the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, without header information you'll need to, at the very least, stream the contents of the file through a filter of some kind looking for your "block" markers.

If you do have header information (or at least some information somewhere as to the offset of your block markers), you could use a memory mapped file:

http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3828586/Using-Memory-Mapped-Files-in-NET-40.htm

This requires .NET 4.0, although you could also use the Win32 API if you're not using .NET 4.

Comment: I am limited to .Net 3.5 at the highest. Do you have any sample code how this might be done using the Win32 API?